# Why bootstrap modal callback fired when a collapse inside modal is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I notice a strange behavior in bootstrap 2.3.2 where i have a collapse panel inside a modal . So when collapse is opened the modal callbacks(e.g.show,shown) are also fired. Cannot figure out why this is happening.
Check here http://www.bootply.com/WHBcMZ6puA#

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2752). People wrote a solution, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#myModal').find('.accordion-toggle').on('hidden', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

It's namespacing problem, which was resolved in bootstrap 3 version. My recommendation, switch to bootstrap v3.

Answer (score 0):

I think the event propagation is causing the issue. Probably (I haven't checked Bootstrap's code) the modal is designed in a way that if some element inside its DOM receives an event, the 'show' callback is executed, effectively revealing the modal popup.

If you block event propagation the callback is never executed. Using this, for example:

```
$('#myModal').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.debug('blocked propagation!');
});
```

Hope it helps as an explanation. There's my fork of your Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/cyvZEYufre

Comment: ooops, side effect! :) ...I think that the propagation has to be cut somewhere else then, but probably is overkill since the modal has to be shown already in order for the accordions to be available. Probably the listener for the modal is actually on the window object or at a very top level and it's designed to work like that, so that any user-produced event inside the DOM of a modal will cause the modal to open...